# how to manipulate data from an input file in c?

Tags: c, io

I am currently working on some code that is meant to take in some data from an input file, find the average and then print the output into a seperate output. I'm not really looking for a full answer, just a hint. I know that I have to somehow store the data in order to manipulate it, but i'm reading the data as a string.
Here is the input:

> 3 11 12 05 1 8.7
>
> 3 11 11 56 143 8.6
>
> 3 11 13 01 163 8.9
>
> 3 10 18 05 1 7.3
>
> 3 10 19 01 1 7.3
>
> 2 28 01 02 2 -1.0
>
> 2 28 09 07 2 -0.5
>
> 6 10 17 00 111 18.7

We are trying to find averages of the last numbers on the right based on the second last numbers on the right.
Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    FILE* input_file = fopen("input_data.txt", "r");
        if (input_file == NULL){
            printf("something went wrong");
            return 1;
        }
    FILE* output_file = fopen("station_averages_summary.txt", "w");
        if (output_file == NULL){
            printf("something went wrong");
            return 1;
        }
    int month, day, hour, minute, station;
    float temp;
    char data[500];
    while((fgets(data, 500, input_file))!= NULL) {
        fscanf(input_file, "%d %d %d %d %d %f", &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &station, &temp);
        fprintf(output_file, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %.2f\n", month, day, hour, minute, station, temp);

            }


    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);
    return 0;
}
```

all this really does is print out the input into an output file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a little more clear your question ? The calculation you want to do isn't clear for me.

But for what I understood, you already have the values read from the file, so just add the calculation after the `fscanf` line and before the `fprintf`. If you need all the values from the file, you have to read all the file and store the values read in an array, iterate through it, calculate what you need and then store in the output file.

Comment: yeah sorry so the second last number would be like a "station" and the last number is the "temperature" so for each station we want to calculate the average temperature, but that is helpful i just cant get the data to be stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a struct to represent a line of the file:

```
struct entry {
    int month, day, hour, minute, station;
    float temp;
};
```

Then, you can declare an array of those structs.  You will have to estimate the number of lines in the file.

```
struct entry input[500]
```

When you read the file, you can fill out the array:

```
size_t counter = 0;
while(fgets(data, 500, input_file != NULL)) {
    struct entry* current = input + counter;
    fscanf(input_file, "%d %d %d %d %d %f", &(current->month), &(current->day), &(current->hour), &(current->minute), &(current->station), &(current->temp));
    ++current;
}
int size = current;
```

Then, you can iterate over the array and calculate the average.